# Unexpected error converting text to date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem converting int values of year, month and day into date value.

```sql
SELECT datefromparts(b.Install_year, b.shipm_month, b.shipm_day)
```

I have already found a solution to the problem, discovering that some values of DAY were 0. But I am curious why things work certain way.

```sql
SELECT datefromparts(2005, 4, b.shipm_day)
```

For testing purpose I set year and month values fixed. Putting there 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 as month and running that in Management Studio I can see the results. Values : 2,4,6,9, and 11 cause the error below:
"Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid."

Anyone has idea why certain values work and other don't?

Comment: Maybe because you're trying to parse some other dates that doesn't exists (like April 31st or February 30th.

Comment: Big clue in the list of failed inputs: “30 days pass September(9), April(4), June(6) and November(11)...blah blah... February(2).”

Answer (score 4):

This would presumably be because the "day" value is 31 and those months do not have 31 days.

`datefromparts()` only constructs valid dates.

This is not that easily fixed because `datefromparts()` doesn't have a "try_" version.

Here is one method:

```
select coalesce(try_convert(date, concat(2005, '-', 4, '-', b.shipm_day)),
                try_convert(date, concat(2005, '-', 4, '-', b.shipm_day - 1)),
                try_convert(date, concat(2005, '-', 4, '-', b.shipm_day - 2)),
                try_convert(date, concat(2005, '-', 4, '-', b.shipm_day - 3))
               )
```